# Is there a reliable and performant positioning strategy to align the dropdown component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, rxjs, preact

I am designing a drop-down component in React/Preact. The interaction of the dropdown is as shown below:

[image]

For the obvious reasons that component can be anywhere on the page and any ancestor DOM element can create new stacking context or use `overflow: hidden`, I cannot use `relative` parent and `absolute` children positioning combo.

I use the `Portal` and render the overlay surface directly as a child of `body` tag when it is opened. **The question here - How to position overlay menu over the anchor element so that their centers collide over each other?**

Few things that must be considered:

1. This is a generic component. The overlay menu can have absolutely any content and thus any size. Size is not known upfront. Call it `InlineModal` or `InlineBox` if you have to.
2. Further, the **anchor element** around which the menu is centered is subject to change its position for many reasons. For example, it is below the content which is having AJAX data which when loads causes the component to shift downwards. Or, even image loading for that matter.
3. While the menu is open, its own size can change due to some check boxes within the menu which add or remove other options from the menu.
4. On edges, the element should be adjusted so that it does not get clipped by the browser window. It should try to fit within the window even if it misses the center alignment.

I can think of few approaches like:

1. Use Rx.js `interval` with `animationFrameScheduler` (internally RAF - `RequestAnimationFrame`) and continuously calculate the fixed position point i.e. `top` and `left`.
2. Use simple `onResize` and `onScroll` handler to re-position the element. But this does not take above mentioned factor into considerations as I have not way to know if the original anchor has shifted due to some other action on the page.

CSS positioning doesn't really matter as the element is appended to `body`; `fixed` and `absolute` will both work fine.

Something that I am trying out with Rx.js and Popmotion:

```
import { action } from 'popmotion';
import { Observable, interval, animationFrameScheduler } from 'rxjs';
import { map, distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';

export type Coordinates = readonly [number, number];

export function stickToCenterAction(reference: HTMLElement, popper: HTMLElement) {

  return action(({ update }) => {
    const sub = stickToCenter(reference, popper)
      .subscribe(([x, y]) => update({ x, y }));

    return {
      stop: () => {
        sub.unsubscribe();
      }
    };
  });

}

function stickToCenter(reference: HTMLElement, popper: HTMLElement): Observable<Coordinates> {
  return interval(0, animationFrameScheduler).pipe(
    map(() => calculateCenter(reference, popper)),
    distinctUntilChanged(([oX, oY], [nX, nY]) => oX === nX && oY === nY ));
}


function calculateCenter(reference: HTMLElement, popper: HTMLElement): Coordinates {
  const [rCenterX, rCenterY] = findCenterForElement(reference);
  const [x, y] = findXYForGivenCenter(popper, [rCenterX, rCenterY]);

  return [x, y];
}

function findCenterForElement(reference: HTMLElement): Coordinates {
  const { left, top, width, height } = reference.getBoundingClientRect();

  const rCenterX = left + (width / 2);
  const rCenterY = top + (height / 2);

  return [rCenterX, rCenterY]
}


function findXYForGivenCenter(elm: HTMLElement, co: Coordinates): Coordinates {

  const [rCenterX, rCenterY] = co;
  const { width, height } = elm.getBoundingClientRect();

  const x = rCenterX - (width / 2);
  const y = rCenterY - (height / 2);

  return [x, y];
}
```

This is how it is consumed in the component:

```
import { styler, tween, composite } from 'popmotion';

export type InlineBoxProps = {
  anchor: (ref: Ref<any>) => ComponentChildren;
  content: (ref: Ref<any>) => ComponentChildren;

  isOpen?: boolean;
};


const scaleEffect = composite({
  opacity: tween({ from: 0, to: 1, duration: 400 }),
  scale: tween({ from: 0.75, to: 1, duration: 240 })
});


export function InlineBox(props: InlineBoxProps) {

  // ... References for anchorElm, contentElm, etc.

  useEffect(() => {

    if (isOpen && anchorElm && contentElm) {

      const elmStyle = styler(contentElm);

      const positionEffect = stickToCenterAction(anchorElm, contentElm)
        .pipe(({ x, y }: any) => ({ y, x }));

      const finalEffect = composite({ boom: scaleEffect, translate: positionEffect })
        .filter((x) => !!x.translate)
        .pipe((({ boom, translate }: any) => ({ ...boom, ...translate })));

      const anim = finalEffect
        .start((v: any) => elmStyle.set(v));

      return () => anim.stop();

    }

  }, [isOpen, anchorElm, contentElm]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {anchor(anchorElmRef)}
      { isOpen
        ? <PortalIntoBody>{content(contentElmRef)}</PortalIntoBody>
        : null }
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

I looked into other implementations like **antd**, **material**, etc. but they have not seemed to consider above possibilities and their Menu is quite restricted at design level to have any generic content.

Comment: A Codesandbox or codepen example would be really helpful